# Does S60 3rd edition support global constants (not WSD)?

Tags: global-variables, symbian, s60-3rd-edition

I'm quite new for Symbian development.

I wrote an ecom dll, some guys told me there's no support for global static variables which got non trivial constructors. And I also read following topic, 
http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/guide/EssentialIdioms/StaticData.html

However, I'm still wondering that if it supports global static constants, even they came up with non trivial constructors.

In the case that if I got lots of global constants, such as strings, how could I deal with them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strings you should use string resource. Check out `RESOURCE TBUF my_string {buf="Hello world"}`
These go into .RC files